# Entity graphs : is there a way to define the attributes that I need to be lazy and let others in default?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I'm using entity graphs for the first time, I know how to define an entity graphs as fetch or load, but the both of them make the defined attributes eager! 
Here I'm asking if there is a way to make the defined attributes lazy and the other relations default

Comment: Nope. Refer to https://java.net/jira/browse/JPA_SPEC-65

Comment: Thank you #Neil ! You saved my time